# FMOD real time audio implementation 

Tags: fmod, realtime, gameaudio, edit

Greetings !
I'm junior sound designer and this is my first game project.
I created sound events in FMOD. 
I need to edit sounds (SFX-s) using FMOD in order to have changes in real-time on the game (installed in the same computer).

What shell I do to get this done ?

Answer (score 1):

Study:

[FMOD Tutorial 1 - Introduction To FMOD Designer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIil0OFtqxc)